# Seam hibernate delete orphan problem

Tags: hibernate, seam, hibernate-mapping, seam2

Im using an entity Employee and inside that a list of UserMaster is defined

```
public class EmployeeMaster{
    private String employee_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private List<UserMaster> userMaster = new ArrayList<UserMaster>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employeeMaster")
    @Cascade(value = {CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})   
    public  List<UserMaster> getUserMaster() {
        return userMaster;
    }
    public void setUserMaster(List<UserMaster> userMaster) {
        this.userMaster = userMaster;
    }
}
```

in my method im calling

```
xsession.saveOrUpdate(employeeMaster);
```

Here im clearing  previous child collection explicitly and add new Child objects

But the delete orphan is not working here .. 
Only the insert query is running Pls Help

> A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" 
>        was no longer referenced by the owning entity

message is showing in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you replaced the collection contained in the loaded entity with `setUserMaster()`.

When collection is configured with `DELETE_ORPHAN`, you cannot replace the collection this way, you need to modify the existing collection using its own methods.

Comment: could u pls explain it a little bit more

Comment: @jennifer: What exactly is unclear? Do you call `setUserMaster()` somewhere? You shouldn't do it.